# Jquery Append function, Adding more elements to ordered list and unordered list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, append

I have two questions:

Q1.I am unable to add all elements to ol and ul. Only first element is added and other elements are not responding. Please help me fix this.
Q2.I want to add ul in between ol for every element with serial numbers. So it looks good for my site.

Please find the below link for output:
http://www.ankooverseas.com/select_university.php

Comment: you are using same id's. you should use different id's to get different results.

Comment: God, there are like 2,000 buttons on my site. should i write code for each button. really? There must be a common code for every button.

Comment: I think you are using loop in php , its better you add a class to it and try to trigger event on class instead of Id

Comment: use data-attributes instead - eg<label data-id="Wichita State University">Wichita State University</label><br />

Comment: data-id is not working. :(

Comment: Someone please help me. @LazyDeveloper class is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".add_univs").click(function() {
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            var univ_name = $('#univ_name',parent).text();
            var course = $('#course',parent ).text();
            var app_fee = $('#app_fee',parent ).text();
            var tuition_fee = $('#tuition_fee',parent).text();
            var ol = $('<ol>',{'id':'shortlist_univs'});
            ol.append("<li>" + univ_name + "</li>").appendTo($('.selectedList'));
            $('<ol>',{'id':'univ_data'}).append("<li>" + course + "</li>")
            .append("<li>" + app_fee + "</li>")
            .append("<li>" + tuition_fee + "</li>")
            .appendTo(ol)

        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
     <div id="enquiry_col">
        <h1>Shortlist Universities on your own</h1>
        <br/>
        <label class="left">Name: </label><input class="left" type="text" size="15" maxlength="40" /><label class="middle">Contact:</label><input class="middle" type="text" size="15" maxlength="40"/><label class="right">E-mail:</label><input class="right" type="text" size="20" maxlength="40"/><br /><br />
        <label class="select_label_text">Select Major:</label><select class="select_menu">
        <option class="option_font">Computer Science</option>
        <option class="option_font">Electrical Engineering</option>
        <option class="option_font">Mechanical Engineering</option>
        <option class="option_font">Civil Engineering</option>
        </select>
   
        <input type="button" value="Search"/>
        <hr />
        <div id="university_list_comp">
        <div id="wichita_comp">
        <label id="univ_name">Wichita State University</label><br />
        <label id="course">Course: Computer Science</label><br />
        <label id="app_fee">Application Fee: $50</label><br />
        <label id="tuition_fee">Tution Fee:$15,400</label><br />
        <button class="add_univs">Add</button>
        </div>
        <div id="franklin_comp">
  <label id="univ_name">Franklin University</label><br />
        <label id="course">Course: Computer Science</label><br />
        <label id="app_fee">Application Fee: $60</label><br />
        <label id="tuition_fee">Tution Fee:$12,000</label><br />
        <button class="add_univs">Add</button>
        </div>
        <div id="gannon_comp">
  <label id="univ_name">Gannon University</label><br />
        <label id="course">Course: Computer Science</label><br />
        <label id="app_fee">Application Fee: $70</label><br />
        <label id="tuition_fee">Tution Fee:$15,000</label><br />
        <button class="add_univs">Add</button>
        </div>
        <div id="wright_comp">
        <label id="univ_name">Wright State University</label><br />
        <label id="course">Course: Computer Science</label><br />
        <label id="app_fee">Application Fee: $50</label><br />
        <label id="tuition_fee">Tution Fee:$12,000</label><br />
        <button class="add_univs">Add</button>
        </div>
        <div id="csula_comp">
        <label id="univ_name">California State University-Los Angeles</label><br />
        <label id="course">Course: Computer Science</label><br />
        <label id="app_fee">Application Fee: $60</label><br />
        <label id="tuition_fee">Tution Fee:$16,000</label><br />
        <button class="add_univs">Add</button>
        </div>
        <div id="kent_comp">
         <label id="univ_name">Kent State University</label><br />
        <label id="course">Course: Computer Science</label><br />
        <label id="app_fee">Application Fee: $80</label><br />
        <label id="tuition_fee">Tution Fee:$11,000</label><br />
        <button class="add_univs">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="university_list_elec">
     <div id="bridgeport_elec">
        <label>University of Bridgeport</label><br />
        <label>Course: Electrical Engineering</label><br />
        <label>Application Fee: $55</label><br />
        <label>Tution Fee:$18,000</label><br />
        <button>Add</button>
        </div>
        <div id="tamuk_elec">
        <label>Texas A&M University-Kingsville</label><br />
        <label>Course: Electrical Engineering</label><br />
        <label>Application Fee: $45</label><br />
        <label>Tution Fee:$16,550</label><br />
        <button>Add</button>
        </div>
        <div id="umassl_elec">
        <label>University of Massachusetts-Lowell</label><br />
        <label>Course: Electrical Engineering</label><br />
        <label>Application Fee: $35</label><br />
        <label>Tution Fee:$17,550</label><br />
        <button>Add</button>
        </div>
        <div id="csulb_elec">
        <label>California State University-Long Beach</label><br />
        <label>Course: Electrical Engineering</label><br />
        <label>Application Fee: $65</label><br />
        <label>Tution Fee:$17,350</label><br />
        <button>Add</button>
        </div>
    
    </div>
</div>
<div id="quick_support">
<h1>Selected Universities</h1>
<p>
  <div class="selectedList" ></div>
<ol id="shortlist_univs">
 <ul id="univ_data">
 </ul>
    
    
</ol>
</p>
```

Updated it , i think your are looking for this output , changes Js code

Comment: Thanks so much. But i have 2 more problems with the code. Please follow the link http://www.ankooverseas.com/check/select_university.php  
1. When i click the add button, i want this current button disappear and enabe remove button for this element alone.
2. I want to remove the elements too, when i click the remove button i want to remove specific content based on which remove button is pressed.
pasting the code in below comments

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".add_univs").click(function() {
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            var univ_name = $('#univ_name',parent).text();
            var course = $('#course',parent ).text();
            var app_fee = $('#app_fee',parent ).text();
            var tuition_fee = $('#tuition_fee',).text();

            $("#shortlist_univs").append("<li>" + univ_name + "</li>");
            $("#univ_data").append("<li>" + course + "</li>");
            $("#univ_data").append("<li>" + app_fee + "</li>");
            $("#univ_data").append("<li>" + tuition_fee + "</li>");

        });
    });
</script>
```

Modified your script this works , add class="add_univs" instead of id in html

Comment: Now check this link http://www.ankooverseas.com/check/select_university.php. Sorting looks bad.

Comment: Output looks weird. Please help me to sort them out in order.

Comment: @user1897595 added new answer